# Changing this from recursion to iteration

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration

Some pseudocode:

```
 func F(int x. int y, array p){
       p[x] = 1;
       if (x<=y){
          for each item in getItems(x,p){
              p = F(item,y,p);
          }
       }
       return p;
    }
```

getItems() returns an array of numbers based on x and p, and isn't important for the sake of this question, but it returns a few numbers that are above and below x. However this means if x is too big then I blow up recursion stack since it'll dig down deep below x.

How can I change this to iteration?

Comment: As it is your program will go into infinite loop (doesnt matter if you use recursion or iteration). Work out the logic first.

Comment: It doesn't go into an infinite loop. It works for smaller bounds. Problem is when the bounds are too large.

Comment: Please show simplified version of `getItems`.  How does it depend on `p` ?

Comment: A silly question: do you pass and return the array by value?

Comment: It shouldn't matter; it just returns a few numbers below x and a few numbers above x based on which elements of p have already been marked (this has to do with prime numbers so there's no nice pattern here if this is why you're asking. It's not a simple clean function, but it shouldn't be necessary for rewriting F)

nm: No, by reference

Comment: Actually it matters a lot, if you can figure out the `x`s in an iterative way, then that's the solution to your question. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by emulating the call stack:

```
struct stackentry {
    int x;
    Item item; // see exercise for reader, below
};

func F(int x, int y, array p){
   dynamic_list_of_stackentry mystack;
  start:
   p[x] = 1;
   if (x<=y){
      for each item in getItems(x,p){
          mystack.push(stackentry(x, item));
          x = item
          goto start
        resume:
          x = mystack.top().x;
          item = mystack.top().item;
          mystack.pop();
      }
   }
   if mystack.size() > 0:
      goto resume
   return p;
}
```

Left as an exercise: change the iteration so that you can store, as part of the stack entry, the collection that you're currently iterating over (from `getItems()`) and your current position in it.

I'm not claiming this is elegant code, but you can refactor from this starting point of a non-recursive function that does the same as your recursive one. For example your next step might be:

```
func F(int x, int y, array p){
   dynamic_list_of_int mystack;
   mystack.push(x)
   while not mystack.empty() {
       x = mystack.top();
       mystack.pop();
       p[x] = 1;
       if (x <= y) {
           for each item in reversed(getItems(x,p)) {
               mystack.push(item);
           }
       }
   }
   return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to keep the recursive version (without the stack overflow) by adding a guard that prevents you from double-processing `x` values

```
func F(int x. int y, array p){
   if(p[x] != 1) {
       p[x] = 1;
       if (x<=y){
           for each item in getItems(x,p){
               p = F(item,y,p);
          }
       }
   }
   return p;
}
```

If some of your array values might have been initialized to 1, then change this to something like

```
if(p[x] != null) {
    p[x] = null;
```

i.e. assign a value that you know isn't used in the initial array.  Then when the function completes its processing, iterate through the array and set all null values to 1.